What word is used instead of ‘coast’ for rivers?
The word ‘coast’ is used for places, cities and regions by the sea or ocean:
West Coast       (by the Pacific Ocean)
Coast of Mar del Plata  (by the Atlantic Ocean)
But, what word is used when the place, city or region is by a river? For example:

The city of Rosario is on the Paraná River:
Coast of Rosario    (wrong?? it is by the Parana River)


BTW, you can use the word coast for the river coast.

@Dúthomhas No, that is not accurate at all.

National Geographic disagrees. • So does Merriam Webster. • Google shows that the term is well and widely understood.

@Dúthomhas RiverCoast is the name of a company and probably used as an SEO term. And the National Geographic thing is an explanation not a term: Banks and Shores
Technically, the land next to rivers and lakes is coastal. But river coasts are called banks and lake coasts are called shores.

@Dúthomhas 1) Philosophically, you can use any word to mean anything, so long as your meaning gets across (see Frindle), so you're right there. But I don't see the word "river" in the MW entry, and the NG entry says "Technically, the land next to rivers and lakes is coastal. But river coasts are called banks and lake coasts are called shores." Also, simple google searches are poor tools to check how common a phrase is. Google ngrams are stronger.

(... though, they too should be used carefully, to avoid false positives from words that are used next to each other in other ways. E.g., note that most of the results of a Google text search "river coast" are for the book River, Coast, and Creek. Also, using ngrams to search for "river coast" and following the results to Google Books does yield some 19th century examples.)

The answers you've gotten vary widely. To get more targeted answers, please edit to give a sample sentence showing how the word would be used. Maybe, say, "I'm looking for a nice house on the ___ of Rosario"? Some proposed answers wouldn't fit with this sentence, but would with others. Voting to close until edited.

@AndyBonner  This OP clearly didn't understand how West Coast is used versus just the word coast, so I'd definitely cut him a break. Also, a lot of the google stuff is: RiverCoast with pictures with copyright.


The word is riverbank or banks of the river.

Merriam Webster:

riverbank
: the bank of a river

bank, also Merriam Webster

2
: the rising ground bordering a lake, river, or sea or forming the edge of a cut or hollow

We lived along the banks of the Mississippi River.


The adjective is riparian, also M-W:

riparian
: relating to or living or located on the bank of a natural watercourse (such as a river) or sometimes of a lake or a tidewater

riparian trees


Bear in mind, East Coast and West Coast of the US refer to geographical regions. Not to the coast of states that are on the coast in those regions.
East Coast for example:
Oxford Dictionary via Google


the eastern seaboard of the US, especially the narrow corridor from Boston to Washington, DC.

The coast of California is not the same as the West Coast.

A city can be located on the bank of some river.



The city of Rosario, Wikipedia:

The city, located 300 km (186 mi) northwest of Buenos Aires on the west bank of the Paraná River, is the third-most populous city in the country after Buenos Aires and Cordoba.

A town/city etc. can be on the bank of a river.
A town/city can be on an ocean or sea.

The term "riverside" can be used.

(OLD)   noun /ˈrɪvəsaɪd/ [singular]
​the ground along either side of a river

(The Study of Medieval London
Walter Besant · 2022)  Always the riverside of London has been a place remarkable for its life, and vividness, its riot and noise, the cheerful cry of battle, […]

the riverside of Rosario



No, riverside is not like banks of a river or riverbanks. Not a synonym.

The banks of the river from [x] all the way to the coast were flooded in the storm. It don't mean riverside. [bad grammar on purpose]

@Lambie When you say that Oakland is on the West Coast, you don't mean at all that it is on the west coastline; similarly, for a river you don't say that the city is on the riverbanks, which is the rather narrow land area between the water and normal land. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=city+on+the+coast%2C+city+on+the+coastline&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=town+on+the+riverside%2Ctown+on+the+riverbanks&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

"The term "riverside" can be used". No, a riverside is not the equivalent of coast for the sea. seaside and riverside mean near or next to the sea or river.

@Lambie Does not "coast" mean "next to the sea"? Does not "riverside" mean "next to a river"? The OP speaks of "coast" and the equivalent in the case of a river; that is enough for me. What are you driving at?

M-W: coast:  the land near a shore : seashore

Being like the energizer bunny with twist ties of the spirit does not help the OP.

@Lambie That is not in the question (looking it up in a dictionary, I see that that is, roughly "sand and rocks", that is in other words "coastline"). There is more than one meaning, that is not the one (SOED: the border of land near the sea; the seashore).  It is not in the question because the OP speaks of cities, which can be on seahores or riverbanks.

"looking it up in a dictionary", you said, What do you think M-W is? MERRIAM WEBSTER DICTIONARY: coast: the land near a shore : seashore

"banks" and "riverside" can be used as in other answers, usually when talking about the area immediately adjacent to the river. But in the case of cities, we often don't use any place word, we just say "on" or "along"

St. Louis is on the Mississippi River.


New Orleans, St. Louis, and Memphis all lie along the Missisippi.


banks and riverbanks are the terms. Riverside just means "by the river". They have a riverside home, for example.

True, although Down By the Riverside

Why is that an "although?" It's what I am saying about riverside.

@Lambie It's using it as a noun, meaning "riverbank", not in attributive form.

riverbank and riverside are nouns. They have different uses. We say: This is a riverside town. It sits on the banks of the X River. We don't generally say: This is a riverbank town. riverside means by the river: a riverside park, a riverside apartment block or house. It does not mean all along its banks. coast is to riverbank as riverside is to seaside.

What does any of this have to do with my answer, which avoids using those words entirely?

Your answer says that banks and riverside can be used for what a river has on each side. banks of a river or riverbanks is not riverside, which means next to a river like seaside means next to the sea and lakeside next to a lake.

There are many nuances in how these words are used, and I'm not going to try to cover it in its entirety. Maybe one of the answers that actually recommends those words should do so.

The less general  term "riverfront" can be used if you want to talk about that part of the riverside that is particularly teeming with life.

(OLD)  noun /ˈrɪvəfrʌnt/  (especially North American English)     ​an area of land next to a river with buildings, shops, restaurants, etc. on it

a luxury riverfront apartment



the riverfront of Rosario


No, riverfront is for a town/city or whatever that has a riverfront, and does not refer to the banks of a river. In fact, you can have a riverfront that does away with the banks of a river altogether.

Riparian is the word for things on river banks.  But that doesn't work with your sentence.

For example, the city of Rosario is on the Paraná River:

Your sentence conveys the information well enough.

riparian
Riparian refers to anything located on or related to the banks of a river, such as riparian wildlife.
The roots of the word riparian are related to rivers, and that's exactly what this word refers to: riparian things have something to do with the banks of a river or stream. A person selling fishing lures by the river has a riparian business. A frog that lives by the river bank is a riparian critter. A riparian state is located alongside a river.

From vocabulary.com

This word is somewhat obscure. I suspect that most native speakers won't be familiar with it.

As far as I know, there is no noun corresponding to this adjective, and the question asks for a noun.

Riparian is scientific jargon, rather than a word for normal use.

Yes, the adjective for along the banks of a river. But not parallel in meaning to coast.

In addition to "bank" as mentioned in other answers, there are other words that convey the same meaning.
For one, a river has a "channel" -- the actual groove or depression in the land, filled with water or not. Therefore, the term "channel side" (singular) and "channel sides" (plural) refers to the land that rises up from the water, as well as (depending on context) more or less land adjacent to the channel. When a river has manmade straight sides or nearly vertical natural sides (such as rock bluffs), one can refer to river "walls".
A "levee" is an artificial river bank, a built-up mound of rocks,soil or other materials, placed to artificially make the bank higher so as to contain floods. In many contexts, the levee is the river bank, and people only use the term "levee" instead of "bank" or "side".
Some terms describing river shape can encompass the water itself as well as the channel sides, depending on context. One could debate whether a "river bend" (a curved section of a river) is the water, the water and the banks, or just the banks of the channel.

How is any of this related to what the land bordering a river versus the land bordering the sea called? coast versus banks.

It's worth thinking about exactly where along a river a settlement is likely to form. Many settlements take their names from a river, but a particular part of that river. Certain geographical features lend themselves to making settlement easier.
Towns like Bournemouth, Exmouth, Plymouth are named due being at the mouth (where the river meets the sea) of the rivers Bourne, Exe, and Plym respectively.
Many towns are named after fords in the river, Watford, Oxford, and Prague spring to mind, these are not named after their rivers (Colne, Thames, and Vlatava respectively) but a description of the crossing itself. Watford a crossing point that was wet, Oxford a place where Oxen could cross, Praha meaning ford or crossing point.
You'll also find towns named after bridges as another crossing point, Fordingbridge, Cambridge, and Mostar, across the rivers Avon, Cam, and Neretva respectively.
So whilst some towns might be named directly after the river (Exeter springs to mind) however many many more seem to be named after river features instead.

How is this relevant? The question was about what borders the sea versus what borders a river...Not how rivers get their names.

I never commented on how rivers were named. I commented about how places that near rivers were named. Just as the question asked "what word is used when the place, city or region is by a river?". Admittedly I didn't give them a single word answer as that would be restrictive, and we should encourage folk to think. It seems you read neither the question nor the answer, however I'm sure your constant interactions will boost your stack-rating. Good luck
